# ZSH on Ubuntu - many applications missing from Start Menu

Tags: zsh

Many applications are missing from start menu after installing ZSH as instructed [here.](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)

How do I restore the applications to start menu, while also keeping ZSH?

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 31,4 GiB of RAM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to /etc/zsh/zprofile fixes the problem.

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```

Only snap applications are missing, and it looks like snap assumes bash to be the startup shell.

[Source.](https://www.realjenius.com/2020/01/12/kde-neon-snap-apps-missing/)